# How to generate multiple temporary access URLs for the same Azure blob?

Tags: rest, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

We are developing different client apps that use files in the Cloud. Files must be stored safely in the Cloud with a secure authorize access. Also it must be possible for several client apps to read those files through a temporary URL at the same time.
We tried to implement this into Azure but we had the following problems:
-   When you stored blobs in private containers and generated Shared Access Keys only one user could read that file a certain time. The system worked like this: the client app asked the web server to generate a public URL for that blob and return it for use. The problem was if one second another client app asked the service to generate a public URL for the same blob. In that moment the first one becomes unusable. 
-   We made the container public but no way we can keep permanent URL to the blobs

So, how can we generate multiple temporary access URLs (Shared keys or similar) for the same blob stored in private containers? 
What would be the best practice to transport the URL from and to Windows Azure without others to catch it and reuse it even if temporary like 20 minutes? Will any solution work with a future CDN integration?

We appreciate your help. 
Thank you!

Comment: "The problem was if one second another client app asked the service to generate a public URL for the same blob. In that moment the first one becomes unusable."

What? That's not how shared access signatures work. Unless maybe you were using a container-level access policy and you were destroying the old one?

Could you share your code?

Comment: Agree with smarx - that doesn't make sense (not how SAS works).  As for your future CDN use question, files in the Windows Azure CDN have to be publically accessible.

Comment: @smarx - I think you are right. I found this:     lPermissions.SharedAccessPolicies.Clear();

Answer (score 0):

You can generate multiple shared access signatures for a blob and they can all be used simultaneously. It sounds like you might be inadvertently revoking the old stored access policy each time you generate a new shared access signature. Fix the problem by keeping (and probably re-using) the old stored access policies. See these links for more information and sample code:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj721951.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee393341.aspx

To protect the shared access signature, you should send it from the server to the client over an encrypted channel. Use SSL or similar for this.

I do not believe a CDN solution would help you with your requirements.